# Actionscript 3, flexSDK, Blocking mouse wheel scrolling when it's over flash stage

Tags: actionscript-3, mouse, mousewheel

I searched for this a lot, but I couldn't find a solution for this 'bug' as it's called here:
http://fcontheweb.com/articles/scrollwheel/

Please, click on first flash, and use mouse wheel, then click on second flash and use mouse wheel again. Now You know perfectly what 'bug' I mean.

The thing is, I believe this bug can be solved WITHOUT externalinterface. This chat is made with AS 3:
http://www.kongregate.com/games/UnknownGuardian/game-development-room-gdr
Open 'codebox', hold ENTER to make a hundred of lines or so, and then test your mouse wheel.

It doesn't use any externalinterface technique (both obviously as it's Kongregate, and confirmed by author), just mx.component.textArea that itself implements the scrolling nicely.

I couldn't achieve that with even.preventDefault or stopPropagation. Any ideas?

E: Thank You, divillysausages! The question still isn't answered in 1% - what is textArea component's workaround?

Comment: I think the TextArea just has this sort of behaviour built in. I'm not sure what workaround they're using, if one

Comment: You are probably right, I couldn't find anything in TextArea source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two methods proposed here: http://gamedev.rasmuswriedtlarsen.com/2010/01/18/quicktip-scrolling-only-in-swf-not-on-page/, but only the first one works on Kongregate

Apparently it uses `ByteArray` and `LocalConnection` to construct an AS2 swf that stops most browsers getting the scroll event

Comment: It works! And it was so easy to implement (but not easy to create the MouseWheel class probably)! Thank You, kind sir!